# How do I pass form values to an action using anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, forms, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I have a form that I would like to pass the values of the form to an action. I also don't want to use a submit button and would like to use struts2 anchor tag. Here is my below code:

```
 <s:form id="form" theme="xhtml" >                  
        <sj:datepicker id="startDate" name="startDate" label="Start Date" required="true"/>       
                                    <sj:datepicker id="endDate" name="endDate" label="End Date" required="true" /> 

    </s:form> 
    <s:url action="excelExport" id="excelurl" > 
    </s:url>
    <s:a formId="form" href="%{excelurl}" onclick="document.forms['form'].submit();" >Export</s:a>
```

The problem here is that the start date and end date are not passed to the action. Can someone advise how to pass the form values to the action. I am using struts2 jquery plugin btw. Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using struts2-jquery-plugin then use it tags  e.g. `<sj:a>`.

Comment: I tried using the sj:a tag but it doesn't call my action then. There is a javascript: void(0) error. I'm not sure what javascript I need to add...If I use <s:a>, my action gets called at least, but the form values don't get passed unfortunately.

Comment: show us the request being sent ? Secondly, do you have a getter/setter for startDate & endDate ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. what request info would be helpful? I do have a getter and setter for start/end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use javascript to get the form values and then dynamically create the url with the form values. A bit hacky but it worked. Let me know if anybody has any more elegant solutions.

```
<s:a id="exportLink" href="%{excelurl}" onclick="document.getElementById   ('exportLink').href=(document.getElementById('exportLink').href + 'startDate=' + document.getElementById('startDate').value + '&endDate=' + document.getElementById('endDate').value ;alert(document.getElementById('exportLink').href);">Export Current View to Excel</s:a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
href="%{excelurl}" onclick="document.forms['form'].submit();
```

According to me **href** will get called once u click on the anchor tag. 
Can you remove the href and provide the action name in the form tag, so that clicking will call the js submit

This might help :)

Comment: I don't want to associate the form with an action since the user could either submit the form and view the data on the web page or export to excel. I tried removing the onclick portion but the form values are still not being passed. I thought if I specified a formId="form" then it would pass the form values, am I wrong?